# Sampling from tensor that depends on a random variable in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, probability, sampling

Is it possible to get samples from a tensor that depends on a random variable in tensorflow? I need to get an approximate sample distribution to use in a loss function to be optimized. Specifically, in the example below, I want to be able to obtain samples of Y_output in order to be able to calculate the mean and variance of the output distribution and use these parameters in a loss function.

```
def sample_weight(mean, phi, seed=1):
    P_epsilon = tf.distributions.Normal(loc=0., scale=1.0)
    epsilon_s = P_epsilon.sample([1])
    s = tf.multiply(epsilon_s, tf.log(1.0+tf.exp(phi)))
    weight_sample = mean + s
    return weight_sample

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 1], name="X")
Y_labels = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 1], name="Y_labels")
sw0 = sample_weight(u0,p0)
sw1 = sample_weight(u1,p1)
Y_output = sw0 + tf.multiply(sw1,X)

loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(labels=Y_labels, predictions=Y_output)
train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.5e-1).minimize(loss)
init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
losses = []
predictions = []

Fx = lambda x: 0.5*x + 5.0
xrnge = 50
xs, ys = build_toy_data(funcx=Fx, stdev=2.0, num=xrnge)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init_op)
    iterations=1000
    for i in range(iterations):
        stat = sess.run(loss, feed_dict={X: xs, Y_labels: ys})
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this answers your question, but: when you have a `Tensor` downstream from a sampling `Op` (e.g., the `Op` created by your call to `P_epsilon.sample([1])`, anytime you call `sess.run` on the downstream `Tensor`, the sample op will be re-run, and produce a new random value. Example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow_probability import distributions as tfd

n = tfd.Normal(0., 1.)
s = n.sample()
y = s**2
sess = tf.Session()  # Don't actually do this -- use context manager
print(sess.run(y))
# ==> 0.13539088
print(sess.run(y))
# ==> 0.15465781
print(sess.run(y))
# ==> 4.7929106
```

If you want a bunch of samples of `y`, you could do

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow_probability import distributions as tfd

n = tfd.Normal(0., 1.)
s = n.sample(100)
y = s**2
sess = tf.Session()  # Don't actually do this -- use context manager
print(sess.run(y))
# ==> vector of 100 squared random normal values
```

We also have some cool tools in `tensorflow_probability` to do the kind of thing you're driving at here. Namely the `Bijector` API and, somewhat simpler, the `trainable_distributions` API.

(Another minor point: I'd suggest using `tf.nn.softplus`, or at a minimum `tf.log1p(tf.exp(x))` instead of `tf.log(1.0 + tf.exp(x))`. The latter has poor numerical properties due to floating point imprecision, which the former are optimized for).

Hope this is some help!

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for the feedback and suggestions. I am aware that using the run function consecutively will yield different random samples. I would, however, like to use this kind of functionality in a cost function, to have multiple terms in the cost function that depends on N random samples. Maybe using trainable distributions could help, but it would be nice to be able to set up a cost function to use multiple samples from a probabilistic network.

Comment: If you want to use the same samples in the cost function every time, I think you have 3 choices:

1. Do `samples_ = sess.run(samples)` then use the result `samples_` downstream
2. Use [SeedStream](https://github.com/tensorflow/probability/blob/master/tensorflow_probability/g3doc/api_docs/python/tfp/distributions/SeedStream.md)
3. Use a `Variable` and `tf.assign` to set the variable to the result of sampling; then the resample will only happen when you run the assign_op